# IntegrationRuntime_3.5.6659.6 (64-bit) unable to install windows 10

Tags: azure

Microsoft integration run time setup.
when am installing software below error getting , can any one give me the solution.

***service integration run time service (DIAHostService) failed to start. verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services**.

Answer (score 0):

For this exception we need to start `integratedruntime` service manually by following the below steps:

goto `start->run->services.msc->click on integratedruntimeservice(DIAHostService)->start`

Note:some times it throws logon exception:

`error 1069: The service did not start due to logon`

in this case right click on `integratedruntime` service and `-->property-->logon` 
 and give your computer password